# How do you calculate the expected value, the variance and the standard deviation of a sum of random variables, regardless of their distribution

Tags: probability, random-variables

I was looking for a formula or something, but I can't find anything anywhere. So, can someone tell me the steps I need to follow in order to do that? I thought that the expected value of the sum was the sum the expected values, but I thought it didn't make any sense. Also, I thought that the standard deviation was the sum of the variances squared, but I can't verify whether that's correct or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Provided they exist, the expectation of a sum will always be the sum of expectations.

The variance of a sum will be the sum of the variances **IF** they are independant.

If you have dependant variables, then
$$
Var\left [\sum X_i\right]= \sum_j \sum_i Cov(X_i,X_j),
$$
where Cov is the covariance between your random variables. Note that for independant variables $X$ and $Y, Cov(X,Y)=0$ and so only the terms $Cov(X_i,X_i)$ remain in the sum above, and the covariance between $X$ and $X$ is precisely its variance.